# Smith normal form over integers (previous exam problem)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm preparing for my exam by doing old exams, but they have no solutions given along with the problems. I'm supposed to find the Smith Normal form of  \begin{pmatrix}2 & 4 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 & 6 \\ 3 & 5 & 7 \end{pmatrix} I ended up with \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 4 \end{pmatrix} which satisifes the conditions of a Smith Normal form, but can someone who's more skilled at this than me check if this is correct? Would be appreciated

Comment: You can ask a computer to check your work.  Try using [Sage](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/) and typing

A = matrix(ZZ, [[2,4,2],[2,4,6],[3,5,7]])
A.smith_form()

Comment: It's quite  correct.